# How to rotate a rectangle toward a node not knowing the angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

In the following picture,

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{|<}{>|}{|}{|}{latex}{latex}
    \def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        %\node at (0,0) {"test: #1 - #2 ..."};
        \begin{scope}[>=latex] % redef arrow for dimension lines
            \draw[|<->|,red,
            decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                    mark=at position .5 with {\node[red,text width=.8cm, text centered] at (0,0.6) {#3};},
            },
            postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
        \end{scope}
    }


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (-4,-2) {};
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (-4, 2) {};
    
    \coordinate (box) at (2,1);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=30,]
        \fill[blue!20!white,draw=blue!80!] ($ (box) + (-1,-0.75) $) rectangle ($ (box) + (1, 0.75) $);
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,] (midL) {};
        \draw[blue, ] ($ (box) + (0,0) $) -- (midL) node (thetaEnd) [blue, right] {};
        \path ($ (box) + (-1,0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=30] {{\sf W}${}_{1}$};
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=-60] {{\sf L}${}_{1}$};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[black, ] ($ (box) $) -- ++ (0.9,0) node (thetaSt) [black,right] {}; % CENTRAL LINE
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta_1$", angle eccentricity=1.7] {angle = thetaSt--box--thetaEnd};


    \coordinate [label={[black,yshift=-2mm]right:{\sf X}}]  (RP) at (0,0);
    \fill[red!70!] (RP) circle (0.1);
    \fill[black!70!] (box) circle (0.1);
    
    \draw[thick,red, shorten >= 4pt, shorten <= 4pt,->] (RP) -- (box) node (Xb) [black,below] {};
    
    \Dimline[($(a)+(2,0)$)][($(b)+(2,0)$)][{\large $d$}] ;
    
    
    \coordinate (txA) at (-2,-2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red ] ($ (txA) + (-.5,-.5) $) rectangle ($ (txA) + (.5,0) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (txA) -- (RP);
    
    \coordinate (rxA) at (-2,2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red] ($ (rxA) + (-.5,0) $) rectangle ($ (rxA) + (.5,0.5) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (rxA) -- (RP);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to rotate the two red triangles such that the side would be perpendicular to the dashed red line toward the red X (node (RP)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can measure the angle with `atan2`. In more detail, I only added

```
let \p1=($(RP)-(txA)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in [rotate=\n1]
```

to the first rectangle path and

```
let \p1=($(RP)-(rxA)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in [rotate=\n1]
```

to the second path to get

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{|<}{>|}{|}{|}{latex}{latex}
    \def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        %\node at (0,0) {"test: #1 - #2 ..."};
        \begin{scope}[>=latex] % redef arrow for dimension lines
            \draw[|<->|,red,
            decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                    mark=at position .5 with {\node[red,text width=.8cm, text centered] at (0,0.6) {#3};},
            },
            postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
        \end{scope}
    }


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (-4,-2) {};
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (-4, 2) {};
    
    \coordinate (box) at (2,1);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=30,]
        \fill[blue!20!white,draw=blue!80!] ($ (box) + (-1,-0.75) $) rectangle ($ (box) + (1, 0.75) $);
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,] (midL) {};
        \draw[blue, ] ($ (box) + (0,0) $) -- (midL) node (thetaEnd) [blue, right] {};
        \path ($ (box) + (-1,0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=30] {{\sf W}${}_{1}$};
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=-60] {{\sf L}${}_{1}$};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[black, ] ($ (box) $) -- ++ (0.9,0) node (thetaSt) [black,right] {}; % CENTRAL LINE
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta_1$", angle eccentricity=1.7] {angle = thetaSt--box--thetaEnd};


    \coordinate [label={[black,yshift=-2mm]right:{\sf X}}]  (RP) at (0,0);
    \fill[red!70!] (RP) circle (0.1);
    \fill[black!70!] (box) circle (0.1);
    
    \draw[thick,red, shorten >= 4pt, shorten <= 4pt,->] (RP) -- (box) node (Xb) [black,below] {};
    
    \Dimline[($(a)+(2,0)$)][($(b)+(2,0)$)][{\large $d$}] ;
    
    
    \coordinate (txA) at (-2,-2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red ] let \p1=($(RP)-(txA)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} 
    in [rotate=\n1] ($ (txA) + (-.5,-.5) $) rectangle ($ (txA) + (.5,0) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (txA) -- (RP);
    
    \coordinate (rxA) at (-2,2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red]  let \p1=($(RP)-(rxA)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} 
    in [rotate=\n1] ($ (rxA) + (-.5,0) $) rectangle ($ (rxA) + (.5,0.5) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (rxA) -- (RP);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I do not explain the question well. I would like to rotate the rectangle but the long side is perpendicular to the dashed line, not parallel.

Comment: @user1993416 Does `[rotate=\n1+90]` instead of `[rotate=\n1]` give you what you want?

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. May you explain a bit what `\y1` and `\x1` are?

Comment: @user1993416 After `l\p1=($(RP)-(txA)$)` `\x1` and `\y1`, respectively, are the x and y components of the vector `(RP)-(txA)`. Then `atan2(]y1,\x1)` is the slope of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution. Rectangles are drawn as `nodes` along the path from `RP` to `txA` (or `rxA`). This way they can be `sloped` to follow the path.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{|<}{>|}{|}{|}{latex}{latex}
    \def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        %\node at (0,0) {"test: #1 - #2 ..."};
        \begin{scope}[>=latex] % redef arrow for dimension lines
            \draw[|<->|,red,
            decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                    mark=at position .5 with {\node[red,text width=.8cm, text centered] at (0,0.6) {#3};},
            },
            postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
        \end{scope}
    }


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (-4,-2) {};
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (-4, 2) {};
    
    \coordinate (box) at (2,1);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=30,]
        \fill[blue!20!white,draw=blue!80!] ($ (box) + (-1,-0.75) $) rectangle ($ (box) + (1, 0.75) $);
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,] (midL) {};
        \draw[blue, ] ($ (box) + (0,0) $) -- (midL) node (thetaEnd) [blue, right] {};
        \path ($ (box) + (-1,0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=30] {{\sf W}${}_{1}$};
        \path ($ (box) + (1,-0.75) $) -- ($ (box) + (1,0.75) $) node[midway,above, rotate=-60] {{\sf L}${}_{1}$};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[black, ] ($ (box) $) -- ++ (0.9,0) node (thetaSt) [black,right] {}; % CENTRAL LINE
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta_1$", angle eccentricity=1.7] {angle = thetaSt--box--thetaEnd};


    \coordinate [label={[black,yshift=-2mm]right:{\sf X}}]  (RP) at (0,0);
    \fill[red!70!] (RP) circle (0.1);
    \fill[black!70!] (box) circle (0.1);
    
    \draw[thick,red, shorten >= 4pt, shorten <= 4pt,->] (RP) -- (box) node (Xb) [black,below] {};
    
    \Dimline[($(a)+(2,0)$)][($(b)+(2,0)$)][{\large $d$}] ;
    
    
    \coordinate (txA) at (-2,-2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red ] ($ (txA) + (-.5,-.5) $) rectangle ($ (txA) + (.5,0) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (RP) -- node[sloped, anchor=east, draw=black, fill=green, at end, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] {} (txA) ;
    
    \coordinate (rxA) at (-2,2);
    \fill[red!30!white, draw=red] ($ (rxA) + (-.5,0) $) rectangle ($ (rxA) + (.5,0.5) $);
    \draw[thick,red, dashed] (RP) -- node[sloped, anchor=east, draw=black, fill=green, at end, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] {} (rxA) ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution.